# How do I find all possible configs in coala?

Tags: linter, coala

In coala, the code analysis software (https://github.com/coala/coala), what's the easiest way to find a list of all the bears/plugins and the list of the configurations ?

Also, how do I get a list of all possible configurations available by all possible bears that I have installed ? I want to understand all the possible options coala has and enable the bears for those specific configs I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

```
$ coala --show-bears
```

to get the whole list of bears installed in your system. If you want more details (such as bear description, settings, supported languages and so on), you can add the `--show-details` flag:

```
$ coala --show-bears --show-details
```

---

There's also web documentation available at **[bear-docs](https://github.com/coala/bear-docs/blob/master/README.rst)**. It is categorized by language and each bear has its own documentation page too: for example, **[PEP8Bear](https://github.com/coala/bear-docs/blob/master/docs/PEP8Bear.rst)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can find list of all bears here:
http://coala.io/#!/languages

When you click on a bear, you will see all optional and non-optional settings.

Answer (score 0):

**All possible bears in a language**, goto

https://coala.io/#/languages

and type in the programming/scripting language name in the search bar to get the list.

---

**All installed bears:**

```
coala --show-bears
```

**with details:**

```
coala --show-bears --show-details
```

**with descriptions(one-liners):**

```
coala --show-bears --show-description
```